# Keep jupyter number if you remove output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to keep the cell number when you remove a jupyter cell output?
The cell number disappear when you remove the output (see image.)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the output, you can hide the output just by double-clicking the Out[]. So that, the cell number will not be disappeared.

Comment: Hidden an output will still keep its content loaded in the browser. The problem is when generating plots in the Notebook, they are loaded in the browser and it becomes slow. The solution is to remove the output as you go. There is a related post on it here.